# Open Gradle project in IntelliJ IDEA, set encoding

Tags: encoding, intellij-idea, gradle

I am working with IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.2 on Windows 7. My projects use Gradle 2.5. Everytime I open a project using `File | Open`, all my files get set to w*indows-1252* encoding. Is there a simple way to set the encoding to *UTF-8* for all files (modules, projects) in `build.gradle` file so that IntelliJ will automatically use this setting?

Even when `File | Other Settings | Default Settings | Encodings | Project encoding` is set to *UTF-8*, files are still being opened as *windows-1252*.

It is possible to go to the settings and set the encoding manually for every file (by applying it to the project root), but this is less than ideal, because each developer has to do that after each clean checkout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the recent versions of IDEA (in my case 2016.1.4) use utf-8 by default. This of course means that this specific problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using IntelliJ IDEA for Windows...

Have you tried the settings ? `Files > Settings` then `Editor > File Encodings` and change `IDE Encoding` and `Project Encoding` to UTF-8.

Comment: That of course work. I am looking for a way to do it from Gradle. I don't want to bother doing this every time I open the project.

Comment: I do not know much about gradle, but I tried to reproduce your problem and it seems that the `Project Encoding` is not kept over a restart...
But, as a workaround, you could define the `Default Encoding` of your root folder to UTF-8 (so all of your files could inherit the setting). It sems to work for me.

Comment: No, my problem is that after opening a Gradle project, the encoding is set to windows-1252. It is possible to preserve this setting on one machine using IntelliJ only, but another developer would have to do the same etc. The question is how to do this from gradle.

Comment: Have you found a solution?